# À quel courant littéraire « Un cœur simple » de Flaubert appartient-il ?

Tags: littérature

Je lis en ce moment *Un Cœur simple* de Flaubert, et je souhaiterais savoir dans quel courant littéraire cette nouvelle se place et quels sont les éléments symboliques qui pourraient le prouver.

Comment: - Le réalisme ?

Comment: La littérature est hors sujet sur ce site. Le vocabulaire de la littérature est dans le périmètre du site, mais cette question porte essentiellement sur la littérature elle-même et pas juste sur la terminologie. Je recommende de reposer la question sur [literature.se] en anglais, et de fermer la question ici.

Comment: This question doesn’t meet a French Language Stack Exchange guideline. It is a specific question about the history  of literature and not a question about vocabulary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Un cœur simple* est une nouvelle réaliste, donc je dirais qu'elle appartient au courant littéraire dit du réalisme.

Answer (score -1):

Bien qu'il y ait une partie de réalisme, je pense que Flaubert fait surtout ressortir sa modernité à travers *« un cœur simple.  »*